# Can't call main Activity from service

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, main-activity

In Service of Keyboard i cant start Main Activity:

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) 
    Log.d(TAG, primaryCode + " PrimaryCode to send");
    if (primaryCode == 6) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, primaryCode + " Greating is command");
    }
```

As a result, an error pops up

LogCat:

```
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/InputEventReceiver(2776): Exception dispatching input event.
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2776): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2776): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2776):   at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2776):   at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2776):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
12-03 10:46:07.613: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2776):   at sample.stand.Keyb.onKey(Keyb.java:162)
```

Comment: post your error log from logcat

Comment: Also, what type of Activity is it as in how is it defined in project manifest as?

Comment: LogCat i'm Put.  <activity android:name="sample.stand.MainActivity"  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"   />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the logCat, he suggests to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag , so try the following:

```
if (primaryCode == 6) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, primaryCode + " Greating is command");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change in the `Manifest.xml` from

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

as

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And call from yours Intent as,..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent);
```

Try this..